# Mantener estilo css de HTML al ser enviado por PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy enviando un HTML usando PHPMailer y, aunque en algunos gestores de correo se ve bien, hay ciertos gestores de correo en los que el estilo del HTML no se mantiene. Tengo los estilos del CSS como inline, pero ciertos aspectos no parecen aplicarse en algunas ocasiones. Estos son algunos de los estilos que no se aplican:

```
<header class = "header" style=" font-size: 24px;text-align:center; padding-bottom:12px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#02AAC8;" >Hello!</header> 

<img src="http://www.image.org/resources/default_theme/img/comunes/logo.png" style="float:right;margin-left:10px" width="200" height="40" />

<div class="body-text" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;text-align:justify;color:#333333;">
```

¿Hay algún método de PHPMailer que permita mantener el estilo original y evite estos cambios?

Comment: Si es cosa del gestor, poco vas a poder hacer.

Comment: Me parece que depende totalmente del gestor de correo que se use para visualizar el mensaje. Por lo que, respondiendo a tu pregunta, me parece que no existe ningún método de PHPMailer con el que puedas solucionar eso.

Comment: Yo tengo una solucion y es hacer tu plantilla HTML en una imagen y luego mapear los botones con el tag map, funciona en todos los navegadores

Comment: Esta página web te ira muy bien para ver que atributos de CSS soporta cada gestor de correos. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/